# Excel: Convert single column of repeating text into multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Easy excel question? (I've looked, and looked...)

How do you take a single column with groupings of TEXT (e.g. A1:A5, A6:A10, A11:A15) and convert those groups into rows (e.g. A1:A5 converts to B1:F1; A6:A10 converts to B2:F2) Thanks. (Note: can't upload image b/c I'm new)

Here's a text example:

CURRENT:
(Convert this column (2000 entries in groups of 5))

```
Trinity
Neo
Morpheous
Agent Smith
Oracle
Dozer
Mouse
Zion
Nebuchadnezzar
The Twins
```

REFORMATTED:
(Data in rows from the groups of 5)

```
Trinity | Neo | Morpheous | Agent Smith | Oracle
Dozer | Mouse | Zion | Nebuchadnezzar | The Twins
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$2000,COLUMNS($A:A)+5*(ROWS($1:1)-1),1)
```

Then copy **C1** to **D1** through **G1**

Then copy **C1** through **G1** downwards.  For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Obviously Gary's way is much quicker , but an easy to understand but dirty way is to do like so

Add Formula's like so( if you are not putting a header row in , then use `=MOD(ROW(A2),5)`

[image]

The data will look like so

[image]

Then filter to 1 on the last column

[image]